# regex to allow "single 0" or " any other number of digits?

Tags: regex

I need a regex to allow either a single 0 or any other number of digits that do not start with zero so:

> 0 or 23443 or 984756 are allowed but 0123 is not allowed.

I have got the following which allows only 1 to 9

```
[1-9]\d
```

Comment: What language are you working with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for a lone 0 or 1-9 followed by any other digits.

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
```

If you want to match numbers inside of larger strings, use the word boundary marker `\b` in place of `^` and `$`:

```
\b(0|[1-9]\d*)\b
```

Comment: would this be any different i was using it in asp.net, it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @xerxes, you'll probably have to double the backslash - I'm not an asp.net user, but it's the most common issue with Strings as regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to force everything into a single regex to do this.

It will be far clearer if you use multiple regexes, each one making a specific check.  In Perl, you would do it like this, but you can adapt it to C# just fine.

```
if ( ($s eq '0') || (($s =~ /^\d+$/) && not ($s =~ /^0/)) )
```

You have made explicitly clear what the intent is:

```
if ( (string is '0') OR ((string is all digits) AND (string does not start with '0')) )
```

Note that the first check to see if the string is `0` doesn't even use a regex at all, because you are comparing to a single value.

Let the expressive form of your host language be used, rather than trying to cram logic into a regex.